# Probablity of losing a dice coin game

Tags: probability

A game consists of tossing a coin and at the same time rolling a dice. A player wins if he gets a Head and 6.
So, the probability of winning this game by a player is:
$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{12}$ 
Now coming to the probability of losing, this is where things started getting awry, even though it seems quite an easy thing.

**Approach one:**

> p(losing) = 1-p(winnng)
>             = $ 1-\frac{1}{12}$
>             = **$\frac{11}{12}$**

**Approach two:**

> p(losing) = (H on the coin and a number other than 6 on dice)
>                                      or
>               (T on the coin and a number other than 6 on dice)
>             = [$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{6}] + [\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{6}]$
>             = **$\frac{10}{12}$**

Which one is correct and where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happens if T + 6 ? You are missing that case in approach two.

Comment: You haven't stated what happens if the player doesn't get the winning combination.  Is the game over or are there other players who get a turn, with the first to hit the winning combination declared the winner?

Comment: The answers given by Bram28 and amd are correct.  In general, a rule of thumb is that if you want to calculate the probability of the negation of an intersection/conjunction, the first method is usually easier.  In fact, if you want to calculate the probability of any union/disjunction, and the events aren't mutually exclusive, it's often easier to calculate 1 - the probability of the conjunction of the complements/negations of the events, rather than trying to formulate and calculate correct sum, which gets more and more complicated with additional events.

Answer (score 3):

Approach 1 is correct

In approach 2, you are forgetting that you also lose when you get Tails and a 6.... which is a probability of $\frac{1}{12}$ ... exactly the difference

Answer (score 1):

The complementary event to “heads and six” is “tails or not six.” However, the event for which you computed the probability is “(heads and not six) or (tails and six),” which isn’t the same thing. The latter excludes the possibility of “tails and six,” which also loses, so you undercounted the possible outcomes. To put it another way, if the result of the coin toss is tails, then *every* outcome of the die roll is a loser.

More generally, the complement of the event $A\cap B$ is $\overline A\cup\overline B$, not $(\overline A\cap B)\cup(A\cap\overline B)$. (This is just one of De Morgan’s laws.) Using inclusion/exclusion, we therefore have $$\Pr(\overline{A\cap B}) = \Pr(\overline A\cup\overline B) = \Pr(\overline A)+\Pr(\overline B)-\Pr(\overline A\cap\overline B).$$ Applying this to your problem produces $\frac12+\frac56-\frac12\cdot\frac56 =\frac{11}{12},$ in agreement with the first method you used.